# How to get multiple elements with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML I want to process with jquery.

Pretty simple but I cannot get around getting all the elements with the same class:

```
<div class="myclass on"></div>
<div class="myclass off"></div>
<div class="myclass on"></div>
```

If I do this

> $(".myclass")

I get only one. Any help?

### EDIT

I actually only want the 'myclass on' to nest some html in each one to get this:

```
<div class="myclass on"><img src="bar.png"></div>
<div class="myclass off"></div>
<div class="myclass on"><img src="bar.png"></div>
```

Comment: `$(".myclass")` returns all element with the class `myclass`

Comment: That should work. What are you doing with it after that?

Comment: It is working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zjErL/

Comment: May be u did some. If you have done `$('.myclass')` it must work. Can you post what you have written.

Comment: Not quite good at writing JS, I did $(".myclass") in the Chrome inspector and only saw one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using for manipulating each element separately. Just the class .on should be sufficient for the selector.

```
  $('.on').each(function(index){
    $(this).html('<img src="bar.png">');
  });
```

The documentation
http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: I was really close and yet so far. Did not know how to traverse the array.

Comment: Using `.myclass.on` would be more safer than just using `.on` in this case though using `.on` also works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are just not combining two classes correctly in the selector? Because this works:

```
$(".myclass.on").html('<img src="bar.png">');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zjErL/1/ (Thanks Arun for the initial jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1):

May be u did some wrong. If you have done $('.myclass') it must work. Can you post your codes.

This works for me like a charm.

```
$(function(){
    $('.myclass').SOMEEVENT(function(e){ // or use div.myclass without problem 
        // do something. It must work.
    });
});
```

OR if you want to iterate through each element, you can use `.each`

```
$(function(){
    $.each($('.myclass'),function(ind, val){
        // do something.
    });
});
```

OR if you want to use additional class like .on or .off

```
$(function(){
    $.each($('.myclass.on'),function(ind, val){
        // do something.
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

To add image to `myclass on`, you can simply do this

```
$(function(){
    $('.myclass.on').html('Your NEW Adding Tag here');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(".myclass.on").css('color', 'red');

Should select elements with both classes.